# Adding a NavBar compnent to react-router-DOM file out side switch makes so none of my content renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working on an app and when I create my front end routes with a Nav bar like I always do nothing renders.  Here is a code Snippet from a pervious app I made:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomeContainer from './components/HomeComponents/HomeContainer'
import NavBar from './components/UniversalCompnents/NavBar'
import CreateContainer from './components/CreateComponents/CreateContainer'
import ReadContainer from './components/ReadComponents/ReadContainer'
import ProfileContainer from './components/ProfileComponents/ProfileContainer'

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomeContainer} />
        <Route exact path="/create" component={CreateContainer} />
        <Route exact path="/profile/:id" component={ProfileContainer} />
        <Route exact path="/read/:id" component={ReadContainer} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Router
```

this displays my nav bar above all my diferent routes correctly.

Now when I do it the same way on my current project:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'



const Router = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <NavBar/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Router
```

as long as the `<NavBar/>` line (or any other code for that matter) is there the page renders blank and I get no errors. What am I doing differently that I'm not seeing?

Thanks ahead of time

**Edit:**

the `<NavBar/>` component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function NavBar() {
    return (
        <nav style={{ height: "10vh", width: "100vw", backgroundColor: "black", color: "white", display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <NavLink to="/" style={{ width: '20vw' }}>Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/gallery" style={{ width: '20vw' }}>Gallery</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/contact" style={{ width: '20vw' }}>Contact</NavLink>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

Comment: What's inside your `NavBar` component?

Comment: @JulienRioux right now its just a place holder with spans instead of links, its a `<div>` with three `<spans>` in each with different content (home, gallery, contact)

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on. If you create a codesandbox example (https://codesandbox.io/), I'll take a look and fix it!

Comment: @JulienRioux Thank you! had a bigger issue with babel and in solving that i accidentally solved this no idea how! if I figure it out  I'll post it